# C++ shared library: Pure virtual function does not cause link error

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, pure-virtual

I have been struggling to understand why I can create a pure virtual function in a header file that has not been implemented in the library I am using, and that this will not cause a link or even run-time failure.. 
The above might be a little imprecise, but here is some code to back it up.

Here is an interface definition:

```
class A
{
public:
    static A* Create();

    virtual ~A() {}

    virtual status_t start() = 0;
    virtual status_t stop() = 0;
};
```

I have a C++ shared library that contains an implementation "AImpl" + the A::Create() function (see below):

```
A* A::Create {return new AImpl;}

class AImpl : public A
{
public:
    A() {}
    virtual ~A() {}

    virtual status_t start() {}
    virtual status_t stop()  {}
};
```

I build the shared library - No problem. 
Now I add another pure virtual function in the header file for Class A:

```
class A
    {
    public:
        static A* Create();

        virtual ~A() {}

        virtual status_t start() = 0;
        virtual status_t stop() = 0;
        virtual status_t write() = 0;
    };
```

I create a test app that uses it:

```
void main()
{
    A* a = A::Create();
    a->start();
    a->stop();
    a->write();
}
```

Now I understand that the above compiles, but I would think that it would fail linking, since there is no implementation for the write() call in the shared library.
Even at runtime, no crash or anything is happening. It just seems like the write call is skipped. Can anyone help explain - it would be greatly appreciated :-)

Thanks - And sorry for the lengthy question, it was a bit hard for me to explain the exact issue in a "single liner"..

Comment: Are you really sure it recompiled after you changed the code? Can you force a rebuild?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that it is re-compiled. But as I see the compiler should not complain. The code is okay. But the implementation is missing in the lib, so I would have guessed a link error.

Comment: Did you also recompile the library? I guess the compilation should fail in `A::create` since `AImpl` is abstract.

Comment: No I did not compile the library - But the point is really - I was surprise that I could compile/link with an old library, without getting any warnings. It seems from comments in general that this is indeed as expected!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's going on is the shared library was built with one version of the `A` class while the executable binary was built with a different version. At this point you've violated the one definition rule and the compiler is free to do anything, including compiling and linking your code successfully. There is no requirement for compiler diagnostics in this situation.

Comment: Thanks - Yes, that seems to be the general conclusion. Compiler/linker will not help me in a situation where I Link with old library when it comes to pure virtual functions.. Surprising to me - but I will have to deal with that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pure virtual functions will never cause anything to fail during linking. Instead, pure virtual functions will cause a compilation error if you try to instantiate the object of an abstract type.

Reminder - an abstract type is a type which has (directly or indirectly through inheritance) at least one pure virtual function which was not overridden.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer - Do you mean to say that it is expected that the above does not cause any error, when I link with a library that uses the old version of A?

Answer (score 0):

This may compile or build, if the solution has been previously built. This means that it is using old object code. Try to do a clean build of your solution, then rebuild it. Once your solution is cleaned. Then try to compile the inherited class. Another thing that may be of concern is that you have declared your inherited class as:

> class AImpl : A { ...  };

My question on this is how is `AImpl` being inherited from `A`? Are you intending `public`, `protected` or `private` inheritance?

**EDIT**

If you are linking to this as a library and your current solution does not show any compile, build, link errors; this is because your current solution is using the old `lib` or `dll` that was already built. If you go back into your library solution and do a clean build, it should not compile, and thus you won't have a newer version of your library to link to.

Comment: Thanks. You are right the real code has public inheritance. I will update the post to show that. I know that re-compiling the shared library (which has the implementation) will cause a compile error. But I was surprised that I could add new pure virtual methods to the header file without getting any compile/link error in the application using the shared lib. Even at run time I don't get errors - Just skipping the call is seems?

Comment: @user6014883 I edited my answer adding a new section explaining what happens with linking against libraries.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the comments. I understand from the comments that Indeed I should not expect any compile/link error with an old library. That was a bit surprising to me - But I will just have to deal with that :-)